# Check for shared values in SQL results

Tags: php, sql, database, web

I've run into a problem in a php and sql system I'm working on. Let's say I have a table structured as so:

```
id   refid   requester  receiver  confirmed
```

And I have two usernames, say, $user1 and $user2. I want to check whether user1 and user2 have ever been connected to the same refid: In other words, for any row in this table, and given two users, have both users ever been either a requester or receiver for the same refid?

I'm having trouble putting this into words, much less code. As an example, let's say I do a

```
SELECT refid FROM thetable WHERE requester=$user1 OR receiver=$user1
```

and it returns something like

```
"1, 7, 9, 12"
```

I then do

```
SELECT refid FROM thetable WHERE requester=$user2 OR receiver=$user2
```

and it returns

```
"2, 3, 9, 10, 12, 13".
```

These two results share at least one returned value, in this case both 9 and 12. I want to be able to check if any sharing like this occurs.

I'm almost certain there's a very simple way to do this, but I can't seem to figure out how, or even come up with a good search string that will actually yield results. Thanks a lot!

Comment: read the result of both queries into an array and check if any of the array values are the same?

Comment: Oh wow I feel like an idiot. PHP array_intersect() sounds like exactly what I need. I find that once I post a question, the answer seems blatantly obvious. You made me think in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: or you could just use intersect between the 2 queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean? Find user1 refid's that are also user2 refid? Use `IN` construction:

```
SELECT refid FROM thetable WHERE requester=$user1 OR receiver=$user1
where refid IN (SELECT refid FROM thetable WHERE requester=$user2 OR receiver=$user2)
```

Alternatively, use `INTERSECT`:

```
SELECT refid FROM thetable WHERE requester=$user1 OR receiver=$user1
INTERSECT
SELECT refid FROM thetable WHERE requester=$user2 OR receiver=$user2
```

Comment: Thanks jarlh, that looks like it should do it. Jeremy C.'s original array idea seems to be workable too, but I like your solution that consolidates it all into a single query.

Comment: Yes, it's usually a good idea to have it all done in one query.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to perform SQL **intersection** query. I want to point something regarding results here in order to better understand the capabilities of MySQL - if you use it of course. Let's say we have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE a (x INT, y VARCHAR(5)); 
CREATE TABLE b (x INT, y VARCHAR(5)); 
INSERT INTO a(x,y) VALUES(1,'A'); 
INSERT INTO a(x,y) VALUES(2,'B'); 
INSERT INTO a(x,y) VALUES(3,'C'); 
INSERT INTO a(x,y) VALUES(4,'D'); 
INSERT INTO b(x,y) VALUES(1,'A'); 
INSERT INTO b(x,y) VALUES(3,'C'); 

SELECT * FROM a; 
+------+------+ 
| x    | y    | 
+------+------+ 
|    1 | A    | 
|    2 | B    | 
|    3 | C    | 
|    4 | D    | 
+------+------+ 
SELECT * FROM b; 
+------+------+ 
| x    | y    | 
+------+------+ 
|    1 | A    | 
|    3 | C    | 
+------+------+
```

The most efficient way to *intersect* select from both tables is something like that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.x AS x, a.y AS y 
FROM a INNER JOIN b USING (x,y);
```

Of course, you may want to use PHP and it's many `array_*` functions to extract the result you need - `array_intersect()` or `array_unique()`.

Comment: Most efficient or not depends on the dbms used. Different products optimizes in different ways. (No one specified here...)